# Unable to deploy PivotalMySQLWeb as stand alone or in local PCF

Tags: maven, cloud-foundry

When i am trying to deploy as stand alone i am getting below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94) ~[PivotalMySQLWeb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipInflaterInputStream.java:52) ~[PivotalMySQLWeb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.Resource.getBytes(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
... 50 common frames omitted
```

and when i am trying to push in my local PCF, i am getting below error.

Staging...

```
warning [/tmp/app/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar]: 804742 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
(attempting to process anyway)
warning [/tmp/app/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar]: 804742 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
(attempting to process anyway)
-----> Java Buildpack Version: v3.13 (offline) | https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#03b493f
-----> Downloading Open Jdk JRE 1.8.0_121 from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/openjdk/trusty/x86_64/openjdk-1.8.0_121.tar.gz (found in cache)
Expanding Open Jdk JRE to .java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre (1.3s)
-----> Downloading Open JDK Like Memory Calculator 2.0.2_RELEASE from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/memory-calculator/trusty/x86_64/memory-calculator-2.0.2_RELEASE.tar.gz (found in cache)
Memory Settings: -Xms681574K -XX:MetaspaceSize=104857K -Xss349K -Xmx681574K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=104857K
-----> Downloading Container Certificate Trust Store 2.0.0_RELEASE from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/container-certificate-trust-store/container-certificate-trust-store-2.0.0_RELEASE.jar (found in cache)
Adding certificates to .java-buildpack/container_certificate_trust_store/truststore.jks (0.9s)
-----> Downloading Spring Auto Reconfiguration 1.10.0_RELEASE from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/auto-reconfiguration/auto-reconfiguration-1.10.0_RELEASE.jar (found in cache)
warning [/tmp/app/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar]: 804742 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
```

(attempting to process anyway)

Comment: It looks like some of the JARs you have are bad.  Did you use Maven or Gradle to download the app's dependencies?  What can happen is that Maven/Gradle fails to download a JAR but that failed JAR gets cached.  The cached JARs are always used going forward because it's the cache.  Then you get errors like this.  The easiest thing is to go into the cache and just delete the directories for the JARs listed.  Maven cache is under `~/.m2/repository` and gradle is `~/.gradle/caches`.  Just look for `tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar` under those folders and delete.  Then rebuild your app and deploy again

Comment: Thanks a lot , this solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some of the JARs you have are bad. When you use Maven or Gradle to download the app's dependencies, what can happen is that Maven/Gradle fails to download a JAR but that failed JAR gets cached. The cached JARs are always used going forward because it's the cache. Then you get errors like what you're seeing.

The easiest thing is to go into the cache and just delete the directories for the JARs listed. Maven cache is under `~/.m2/repository` and gradle is `~/.gradle/caches`. Just look for `tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar` (or whatever JAR is giving the error) under those folders and delete. Then rebuild your app and deploy again.